# How do I install Minecraft mods for Xbox 360

Tags: mods, minecraft-legacy-console

I was just wondering how I would get the skin packs and different mods for Xbox 360.

Comment: -1. This question shows no research or attempt to resolve the question.

Comment: You can get skin packs from Minecraft store but you cannot make your own

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There is no legal way to mod your Xbox 360. There used to be a way, but it was illegal. The only add-ons you can get on the Xbox 360 and other consoles are:

on Consoles(like xbox360, etc):

- Skin Packs [Used to change the look of your character.]
- Texture Packs [Worlds will have different looks due to textures.]
- Mash Up Packs [Themed world with a different texture.]
- Theme [Backgrounds in the Xbox 360 Dashboard.]
- Gamerpics [Used as a profile image.]
- Avatar Items [Minecraft stuff you can put on your Xbox Avatar.]

on PC:

- Skins
- Mods
- Texture Packs
- Maps
- Resource Packs